# Add semi-transparent box around subtitle

Tags: ffmpeg, filter, linux

Hey guys how can I add box around subtitle like on picture with ffmpeg
here is mi current command

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -strict -2 -vf "subtitles=subtitle.srt:force_style='FontName=ubuntu,fontsize=30',scale=720:-1" -qscale:v 3  Movie.avi
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -strict -2 -vf "subtitles=subtitle.srt:force_style='FontName=ubuntu,fontsize=30,BorderStyle=3,OutlineColour=&H80000000',scale=720:-1" -qscale:v 3  Movie.avi
```

See Style [Fields](http://fileformats.wikia.com/wiki/SubStation_Alpha#Fields) and [Data Types](http://fileformats.wikia.com/wiki/SubStation_Alpha#Data_types) for tag info and color syntax.